# How to fix VS Code launch error: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: visual-studio-code

The follwing code in launch.json:

```
"configurations":
["args": ["--variable_schema='(?!global_step|(?:.*/|^)LARSOptimizer|head)'", 
...]
```

was being transferred to

```
 --variable_schema=\'(?global_step|(?:.*/|^)LARSOptimizer|head|(?:.*/|^)LARSOptimizer|head)\'
```

by VSC when launch my app, which causes following error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

How to disable VSC doing above converting?

## Edit -- after applying the proposed changes:

The full json:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "run.py",
        "args": [ "--mode=train_then_eval", "--train_mode=finetune", 
        "--fine_tune_after_block=4", "--zero_init_logits_layer=True", 
        "--variable_schema=\\(?\\!global_step\\|\\(?:.*/\\|^\\)LARSOptimizer\\|head\\)"
        "--global_bn=False", "--optimizer=momentum", "--learning_rate=0.1", "--weight_decay=0.0",
        "--train_epochs=100", "--train_batch_size=512", "--warmup_epochs=0",  "--data_dir=data2",
        "--dataset=mycervical", "--image_size=100", "--eval_split=test", "--resnet_depth=18", 
        "--checkpoint=./tmp/simclr_test", "--model_dir=./tmp/simclr_test_ft", "--use_tpu=False"],
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }
]
```

The output resulting from the actual json:

```
...rain_then_eval
 --train_mode=finetune
 --fine_tune_after_block=4
 --zero_init_logits_layer=True
 --variable_schema=\(?\\!global_step\\|\(?:.*/\\|^\)LARSOptimizer\\|head\)
 --global_bn=False
 --optimizer=momentum
 --learning_rate=0.1
 --weight_decay=0.0 
 --train_epochs=100
 --train_batch_size=512
 --warmup_epochs=0
 --data_dir=data2
 --dataset=mycervical
 --image_size=100
 --eval_split=test
 --resnet_depth=18
 --checkpoint=./tmp/simclr_test
 --model_dir=./tmp/simclr_test_ft
 --use_tpu=False
 bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: try replacing `'` with `\"`

Comment: doesn't work, the cmd became to:
```
--variable_schema=\"(?global_step|(?:.*/|^)LARSOptimizer|head|(?:.*/|^)LARSOptimizer|head)\" 
```
causing same error.

Comment: try this workaround until you find a better solution: `--variable_schema=\\(?\\!global_step\\|\\(?:.*/\\|^\\)LARSOptimizer\\|head\\)`

Comment: Still not work. the "\" keeps stack up.

Comment: what means doesn't work, show the output please. could you provide the full json? and where do you launch it, cygwin or windows?

Comment: It is udner VSC of Macbook Pro.  The full launch.json:
```

Comment: it's not in the comment, can you add it to your topic? click here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61201718/edit or click the edit button

Comment: It is under VSC of Macbook Pro.  Full json is too long, cut off some params. 
`
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "run.py",
            "args": [ "--mode=train_then_eval", "--train_mode=finetune", 
            "--variable_schema=\\(?\\!global_step\\|\\(?:.*/\\|^\\)LARSOptimizer\\|head\\)"
            "--global_bn=False", "--optimizer=momentum", "--learning_rate=0.1", "--weight_decay=0.0",
            }
    ]
}
`

Comment: output error:
``` 
rain_then_eval --train_mode=finetune --fine_tune_after_block=4 --zero_init_logits_layer=True --variable_schema=\\(?\\!global_step\\|\\(?:.*/\\|^\\)LARSOptimizer\\|head\\) --global_bn=False --optimizer=momentum --learning_rate=0.1 --weight_decay=0.0 --train_epochs=100 --train_batch_size=512 --warmup_epochs=0 --data_dir=data2 --dataset=mycervical --image_size=100 --eval_split=test --resnet_depth=18 --checkpoint=./tmp/simclr_test --model_dir=./tmp/simclr_test_ft --use_tpu=False 
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: it's better to see it in full, could you edit your topic and add it in there?

Comment: full json added.

Comment: do you know what Python extension is installed in your VSC? and what is the exact output you get with this actual setup?

Comment: the setting I proposed is getting transferred to the right string, if you get something different please show the output as requested, otherwise I'll flag this topic to be closed

Comment: the output error I posted 2 days ago as "output error...". the related VSC extension is Php extension made by Microsoft.

Comment: I've added the text for you, please check & adjust. Double check the number of backslashes you see. Here I get `variable_schema=\(?\!global_step\|\(?:.*/\|^\)LARSOptimizer\|head\)`

Comment: Following your suggestion, the output is: 
   variable_schema=?global_step?:.*/^LARSOptimizerhead 
Need the output to be: 
  variable_schema='(?!global_step|(?:.*/|^)LARSOptimizer|head)'

Comment: maybe you got my comment wrong, I was saying when I apply the change I was proposing, `\\(?\\!global_step\\|\\(?:.*/\\|^\\)LARSOptimizer\\|head\\)`, then I get this output which is ok at least for bash: `\(?\!global_step\|\(?:.*/\|^\)LARSOptimizer\|head\)`

Comment: did you really get a `bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('` with this? if you observe something else then edit your topic and describe as thorough as you can, so other readers know what is going on at the moment

Comment: I double-checked, the output error is correct.

Comment: Well, looks like your VSC behavior differs from mine when it comes to handle `\\\` - and also the single quotes are being passed through as is. Maybe you should retry from a clean installation. I'm using the MS Python extension.

Comment: try this `variable_schema=\\(?!global_step|\\(?:.*/|^\\)LARSOptimizer|head\\)`

Comment: Tried... No luck, still error: variable_schema=\\(?global_step|(?:.*/|^)LARSOptimizer|head|\\(?:.*/|^\\)LARSOptimizer|head\\) --global_bn=False --optimizer=momentum --learning_rate=0.1 --weight_decay=0.0 --train_epochs=100 --train_batch_size=512 --warmup_epochs=0 --data_dir=data2 --dataset=mycervical --image_size=100 --eval_split=test --resnet_depth=18 --checkpoint=./tmp/simclr_test --model_dir=./tmp/simclr_test_ft --use_tpu=False 
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: Yes, something wrong with VSC's extension, because it works fine before I installed a bunch of extensions, and also upgraded to latest VSC... don't know which one or combinations cause such error.  I shall do a clean installation once I finished my current projects. for now my workaround is given the value in codes.

Comment: if you're still looking for an answer I suggest to add the list of extensions to your question